# How to find my MAC-Address whith ifconfig. Ubuntu

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-18.04, mac-address

ifconfig command in terminal returns me this:

br-6c00ce02a4d1: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:a7:9c:09:f6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-79dcff94aa92: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:43ff:fe69:e8da  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 02:42:43:69:e8:da  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 409826  bytes 52651648 (52.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 327652  bytes 32244665 (32.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:7f:f8:ea:d0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        ether 88:88:88:88:87:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf7100000-f7120000

enp2s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.5.206  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.8.5.255
        inet6 fe80::c35e:21cc:86bf:8769  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 50:3e:aa:0f:6e:39  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 851931  bytes 397066035 (397.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 140839  bytes 17350575 (17.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 774896  bytes 88441796 (88.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 774896  bytes 88441796 (88.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth30c9ef6: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::881f:69ff:fe26:41a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 8a:1f:69:26:04:1a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 435713  bytes 60277342 (60.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 340936  bytes 33455896 (33.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth95023cb: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::6427:47ff:fef2:f46  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 66:27:47:f2:0f:46  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13223  bytes 1204242 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26174  bytes 1920551 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Which one is my MAC-Address?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command:

```
$ ip addr show
```

The `link/ether` field of the output is the MAC address.

Comment: it returns me 10 answers:

Comment: 1: lo: link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00; 

2: enp2s0: link/ether 50:3e:aa:0f:6e:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;  

4: br-6c00ce02a4d1: link/ether 02:42:09:5f:b5:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;  

5: br-79dcff94aa92: link/ether 02:42:36:64:d2:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;  

6: docker0: link/ether 02:42:83:a9:37:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;  

8: veth70bbd3e@if7: link/ether 2e:21:15:c8:39:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0;  

10: vethf0d7962@if9: link/ether e6:c3:ce:69:c0:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1;

Comment: Okay - I only received one.

Have you tried:
"ifconfig | grep HWaddr" ?

Comment: that is the problem! I receive 10, and there is no HWaddr. "ifconfig | grep HWaddr" returns nothing

Comment: Sorry - then I have no clue. I'm new to linux.